# Session Facade in the world of Spring/Hibernate - is it still relevant?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

How would we implement a Session Facade design pattern in the Spring application? Would the role of the Session facade be simply served by the service bean class that would be annotated for the transactions and will have a session scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Spring service (with singleton scope) is like a local stateless session bean, it is an implementation of the Session Facade pattern, only for applications that are not distributed. Spring does make the case that in most cases services don't need to be distributed and that the distributed aspects of Session facade are not as all-pervasive as J2EE made them out to be.

(When you say "session scope" it sounds like you're confusing session as in transactional with session as in HttpSession, because Spring uses the term session scope to refer to HttpSessions. (At least it's confusing me about what's intended.) My reading of [the Session facade description](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/SessionFacade.html) leads me to think it doesn't have anything to do with an HttpSession.)

Anyway, I'd say the basic goal of encapsulating complexity is still valid. In some cases the goal of giving distributed access is still very valid, it's just not the default case like J2EE tried to make it out to be. And Seam makes a case for stateful session beans still being relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I was referring to the "session" in my question is that Session Facade would normally be available for the duration of the session so that all the requests from the web tier would go to that same Session Facade and EJB server will create a pool of session bean instances. Since the default scope for the Spring bean is singleton, one Spring bean will be shared by all the requests which I would think can be a problem for many concurrent requests for time-consuming data retrievals, right?

Comment: LeoNYC: a) with spring of course it's stateless and not pooled, it's not a stateful session bean. the pool might run out of connections or the rdbms might fall over but concurrency shouldn't be an issue for the (stateless) service.

Comment: @LeoNYC: you might get a better answer if you gave more detail. if you have an idea of something that makes session facade not relevant describe it briefly. otherwise we don't know where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Session should be associated with the web tier, not services.

Services do indeed own transactions, so they should have that annotation.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I am trying to understand how would the concept of Session Facade from the EJB world translates to the Spring world of annotated transactions, singleton beans (injected/annotated), eit.